# Create android project from existing source in eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

I try to create an android project from existing source and when I choose the folder I get an error :
An existing directory name must be specified.

I dont understand why I get this error I choose the directory of the project.

image link : https://i.stack.imgur.com/bZLDR.png

I realy need help...

Comment: Use Import project from File Menu..

Comment: Better change the folder name and try again if not working create a new project and copy paste the project folder in project explorer

Answer (score 1):

Solution is to select the parent directory. So if you already have a structure

```
parent
    project
        <AndroidManifest.xml and friends>
```

then select "parent" instead of "project". Use the "Browse" button instead of copy-pasting the path.

Answer (score 0):

Well, after you have selected the project from the directory, and u still see the error symbol,

now dont make any changes to the directory at all, but try to toggle the radio buttons, and if possible even try to check and uncheck the check box, finally bring everything as it was..... the check box unchecked, and radio button at create an android project from existing source selected, u will see the error is gone, that happens in my eclipse

Comment: I try to understand what you suggest but I dont sucess to fix that.

Answer (score 0):

Goto:

> File > Import > Existing Projects into Workspace

and select the root folder of your project.

Comment: Why not the other option, "Existing Android Code Into Workspace"?